# How to apply coupon code if specific products are available on the cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, coupon, code, multiple

The cart contains two products ex: product1+product2 then only my discount can be applied, otherwise should not allow even individual also. Based on SKU

Comment: Magento 1 or 2 ?

Comment: Magento 1 .9.2.1

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if any problem.

Comment: if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark, hit that tickmark for right answer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Admin > promotions > shopping cart price rule`

**1) Create new rule**

- Add your rule information in the first tab.
- In condition, tab makes condition as below the image.
  [image]
- In action tab set discount amount.

Clear cache and check now.

Comment: Let me verify and check

Comment: Let me know if any issue is there.

Comment: See, my product1 & product2 both the values are 14,999 INR each. Now I'm giving a discount amount is 14,998 INR, So, when I was applied the same rule (the one which you shared). Grand total is 2 INR which is not good. Actually it comes 15,000 INR. HOW??

Comment: What discount do you want to apply percentage or fix?

Comment: Hey got it man, I had rectified